# NullReferenceException in FindGameObjectWithTag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I've a panel in my scene (ErrorMessage), I've been disabled it in the editor and writed this in my C# script:

```
            if(getUsernameResponse == "Login OK") {
                Application.LoadLevel("LobbyUI");
            } else {
                GameObject ErrorMessage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ErrorMessage");
                ErrorMessage.SetActive(true);
            }
```

The script should enable (show) my `ErrorMessage` if `getUsernameResponse` have a different response of "Login OK".. but when I start the liveDemo I see this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object) in row:41 (ErrorMessage.SetActive(true);)

I've tried to enable the `ErrorMessage` from the editor and disable with

```
if(getUsernameResponse == "Login OK") {
                Application.LoadLevel("LobbyUI");
            } else {
                GameObject ErrorMessage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ErrorMessage");
                ErrorMessage.SetActive(false);
            }
```

in my source and it works fine, how can I disable `ErrorMessage` (UI.Panel) from my script?

Thanks for support.

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find the problem

Comment: Have you _ever_ read the link that I provide?

Comment: @MirkoBrombin `NullReferenceException` are not the sole domain of `Unity3D`.  You'd be surprised where else they occur.  You really should take a look at Soner's fine suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply means that:

```
GameObject ErrorMessage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ErrorMessage");
```

is not finding the game object.

Probably because you did not actually put a tag on the GameObject, or the tag is spelled wrong. And be sure to remember layers are not tags!

Really though, I don't know your whole setup, but my suspicion is whatever your doing, you really shouldn't be doing. Creating a tag for an errorMessage dialogue? I've written a lot of UI's in Unity. Never have a I tagged anything in a UI. Tagging should be used for very generic grouping of types of objects in the scene that you need to easily grab as a group. TeamA, TeamB, AI, powerup. It should not be used for grabbing just one object, of a very specific nature.

I would use GameObject.Find and search for it by name of the actual GameObject.

Or I would do what Miron Alex said and create a slot in the inspector, then drag the GameObject into it. Which ideally should be a serialized private variable.

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject errorMessage;
```

Comment: this solved my problem thanks, I've declared my UI.Panel as a GameObject thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A NullReferenceException is thrown when an object is "null" as in, it does not exist.
In your code, the method

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ErrorMessage");
```

didn't find any object with the "ErrorMessage" tag, which means it returned "null" and assigned "null" to the ErrorMessage GameObject.
When you are trying to call a method on a "null" object it will throw a "NullReferenceException" because a "null" value doesn't know anything about the "SetActive(bool value)" method (As a GameObject does).

Make sure you have an object tagged as "errorMessage" in the scene.
To make this easier, make a public GameObject in your code, name it ErrorMessage and assign it in the inspector.

```
public GameObject errorMessage;

if(getUsernameResponse == "Login OK") 
{
   Application.LoadLevel("LobbyUI");
} 
else 
{
   errorMessage.SetActive(false);
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: That does not really answer the question **when there is no object in the scene tagged as `ErrorMessage`** or assigned to your `errorMessage` field.  Your code is **not** checking for `null`s.  Plus the OP is using `tags`, not wanting to specifically assign an object to a behaviour. OP asked for fixes for _"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"_ which can still happen in your code.   Consider revising.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks, i try this today, let you know.

Comment: This not solved my problem, i've already declared ErrorMesage (ErrorMessage not errorMessage) in my script:
GameObject ErrorMessage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ErrorMessage");

Comment: You haven't answered if you have placed the tag "ErrorMessage" in the editor, which is likely the solution to your problem.

Comment: this solved my problem thanks, I've declared my UI.Panel as a GameObject thanks.